# Good research papers and tutorials for creation of image processing tool/application (free)

Tags: image-processing

I'm looking for good research papers and tutorials for creation of image processing tool/application which are free. They may not have full-blown description. Papers and tutorials dedicated to a single feature are good enough. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not any papers for it, but if you take a look at the source code for [AForge.NET](http://code.google.com/p/aforge/) you will be able to see how several image processing algorithms are implemented.

The project comprises of the core library and a GUI application that lets you try out the filters. So it will give you and idea of what is involved.